# Convert an empty $_REQUEST parameter into an integer in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a wordpress plugin, and I'm having a hard time understanding **another** piece of code.

The plugin is : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/

This time I have this following few lines:

```
$wslp = @ (int) $_REQUEST["wslp"];

if( $wslp < 1 || $wslp > 6 ){
    $wslp = 1;
}
```

My concern is, what does `$wslp` equal to when the `wslp` parameter is not set ( == when the `$_request` is not set)

The next line gets a page by this number so it can't be just empty or `null`...

Comment: Why didn't you just echo it out and see what it is...?

Comment: Surely the result would be zero, as an integer of a null value renders zero. Then your if clause will turn it to one? Isn't that the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `@` is used to suppress PHP warnings.
- When using `(int)`, anything that cannot be converted to an integer becomes `0`.

So, when `$_REQUEST` does not contain the key `wslp`, `$_REQUEST["wslp"]` returns `NULL` (with an *undefined offset* warning) and `(int) NULL` yields `0`.

## Edit

A much better way to grab value from query string, convert it to desired type, validate it, and fallback default (e.g. when value is missing or invalid) is to use the PHP [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function:

```
$wslp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "wslp", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    "options" => array(
        "default" => 1,
        "min_range" => 1,
        "max_range" => 6
    )
));
```

Comment: I didn't see your edit until now. It looks much simpler and better code-wise too! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It gets zero.

```
(int) undefined === 0
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/EMBAK5Qq)

Comment: Woah cool site! Looks really useful :) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

`$wslp` is being [cast to an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting). The `@` statement hides any notices/warnings for a non-existant `"wslp"` entry in the `$_REQUEST` array.

Comment: I know all that. I just wanted to know what will be the output of it when `NULL` / undefined is being cast into an integer. Thanks anyways :)